# Why does AD3AD08 represent a valid date in the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
DateTime.Parse("AD3AD08")

[2017-08-03 12:00:00 AM]
```

Why does that string (which looks like just a normal hex string to me) get parsed successfully as a date? I can see the 3 and the 8 get parsed as months and days. But otherwise it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Works if i change my current culture to `en-US` or `en-GB`, don't know why either

Comment: Even for `DateTime.Parse("AD3AD08", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: It is the era name (AD = anno domini)

Comment: Probably @xanatos is right AD - era, 3A - month (march), D08 - date/day

Comment: @alex I'll say that the `Era` is interpreted both as the Era and as a "separator", and it can be used even if it isn't included in the datetime pattern and can be used multiple times.

Comment: shouldn'd be era `A.D.` instead of `AD` http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,5064

Comment: I tried `AD3AD08AD10` and it says `3/8/2010 12:00 AM` (August 3, 2010, depending on applied local machine culture it gives different results). Seems that AD is a hexadecimal Unicode "soft hyphen" representation to separate date components.

Comment: Even if DateTime.Parse was treating arbitrary alphanumeric sequences as hex codepoints - which itself is already unlikely - a soft hyphen isn't a separator, so why would it be treated like one?

Comment: For anyone who's interested in the context around this question, see https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/265

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You can use what [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetEraName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.geteraname(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`GetAbbreviatedEraName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatederaname(v=vs.110).aspx) return as delimiter, ignoring the case. The order is: day, month, year (optional).

---

It seems you can always use the calendar's current [era's abbreviated name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatederaname(v=vs.110).aspx) or [full era-name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.geteraname(v=vs.110).aspx) as delimiter for the DateTime tokens. For english cultures it is `AD` or `A.D.`, e.g. for german cultures it is `n. Chr.`.

```
var enCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = enCulture;
var fi = enCulture.DateTimeFormat;
int currentEra = enCulture.Calendar.GetEra(DateTime.Now);
var eraName = fi.GetEraName(currentEra);
var shortEra = fi.GetAbbreviatedEraName(currentEra);
var date = DateTime.Parse($"{shortEra}3{shortEra}08"); // AD or A.D. works

var deCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = deCulture;
fi = deCulture.DateTimeFormat;
currentEra = deCulture.Calendar.GetEra(DateTime.Now);
eraName = fi.GetEraName(currentEra);
shortEra = fi.GetAbbreviatedEraName(currentEra);
date = DateTime.Parse($"{shortEra}3{shortEra}08");  // n. Chr. works
```

Interestingly it is case-insensitive, so `ad` works also. That is documented in [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetEra`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getera(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The era name is the name a calendar uses to refer to a period of time
>   reckoned from a fixed point or event. For example, "A.D." or "C.E." is
>   the current era in the Gregorian calendar. The comparison with eraName
>   is **case-insensitive**, for example, "A.D." is equivalent to "a.d.".

The gregorian calendar has only one era, so `Calendar.GetEra(DateTime.Now)` isn't really  necessary.  I haven't found any further documentation yet.

Here are some samples that all work and will be parsed to christmas 2017:

```
DateTime christmas  = DateTime.Parse("ad25ad12ad2017ad");
christmas = DateTime.Parse("AD25ad12ad2017");
christmas = DateTime.Parse("25ad12ad2017AD");
christmas = DateTime.Parse("25ad12ad2017");
christmas = DateTime.Parse("A.D.25ad12ad2017");
christmas = DateTime.Parse("A.D.25ad12ad");  // current year is used
christmas = DateTime.Parse("A.D.25ad12");    // current year is used
```

Comment: As that link points out, the current era is known as `A.D.` *or* `C.E.` and yet we can't use `CE` as the "separator".

Comment: Accordingly to the reference source, your answer is correct. I only wonder why such a messy choice. I mean, accepting the era *after* the date would have a sense, but accepting it in any place...wouldn't be confusing?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: only what `GetEraName` or `GetAbbreviatedEraName` return can be used which is `A.D.`/`AD`.

Comment: @MarioVernari: yes confusing, but a separator that also includes informations about the current era and culture is not stupid at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, it depends on the context. If the purpose is the UI, I find it totally uncomprehensible. If it's intended for some internal representation (e.g. serialization), I'd have used the negative sign for the year component. Just my option, though...

Comment: Using `BC` as a separator also fails.

Answer (score 9):

You can confirm that this is era and not some UTF encoded character by modifying culture abbreviated era name (era name is stored in `DateTimeFormatInfo.m_abbrevEraNames` and `DateTimeFormatInfo.m_abbrevEnglishEraNames` private fields, and for invariant culture abbreviated era name is string array with just one value - "AD"). `m_eraNames` field also stores full (non-abbreviated) era name ("A.D." for invariant culture) which can also be used instead of "AD".

```
var cul = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();                        
// set DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedEraNames to "BLA"
typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetField("m_abbrevEraNames", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .SetValue(cul.DateTimeFormat, new string[] {"BLA"});
// set DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedEnglishEraNames to "BLA"
typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetField("m_abbrevEnglishEraNames", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .SetValue(cul.DateTimeFormat, new string[] { "BLA" });

var date = DateTime.Parse("AD03AD08", cul); // now it fails
var date = DateTime.Parse("A.D.03A.D.08", cul); // still works because we
// did not modify non-abbreviated era name
var date = DateTime.Parse("BLA03BLA08", cul); // this one works
```

Now why it treats era name like that is not quite obvious... Probably after meeting such token it sets date era and continues parsing, so it serves as separator in a sense it just moves to parsing next token after this one. Documentation for `DateTime.Parse` states that:

> This method attempts to parse string completely and avoid throwing a
>   FormatException. It ignores unrecognized data if possible and fills in
>   missing month, day, and year information with the current date

While this does not mention anything about eras - such behavior aligns with "avoid throwing FormatException whenever possible" design.